# ng-model doesn't work when within angular bootstrap ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ng-model doesn't work like this : [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sz5WqVJrk0lW6vLx0GDX?p=preview)

I tried to alert ng-model="selectedFriend" and expect a pop-up of friend's name, but something is wrong when it's used within tab's content of angular bootstrap ui.

```
        <select ng-model="friendsModel" ng-options="friend.name for friend in myFriends.friends.data">
    <option value="">Select friend</option>
    </select>
```

I suspect it was $scope issue because it work fine here [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/qcbS2ob6MXbv33QDBrxP?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tabs are creating a new scope and thus you need to add a "famous dot" in your `ng-model` expression. Those scope-related issues are quite often and you can observe them even with built-in directives like `ngInclude`.

Finally, here is a working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/PPGA8SBwHeEQNAQCZT3K?p=preview

Comment: very confusing, any other method?

Comment: especially this line   $scope.friends = {
    model: undefined
  };

Comment: @user3522457 have a look at this comprehensive article to understand why this is needed and what are the alternatives: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: so tab became the parent's scope of selectedfriend since i placed them within tab?

Answer (score 0):

You can even pass `friendsModel` as a parameter to `selectFriend()` method

```
<button ng-click="selectFriend(friendsModel)">select</button>
```

and in JS

```
$scope.selectFriend = function(friendsModel){
    console.log(friendsModel);
  };
```

Comment: so I still declare ng-model="selectFriend"?

Comment: Yes. You have to still declare.